# 7-Zip slows down over time on Ubuntu but not Windows

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, ntfs, nautilus

I have a directory called `Pages` of 2.2 million HTML files (about 80 GB) on an Ubuntu server. I compressed it with 7-Zip using this command:

```
7z a -mx=9 Pages.7z Pages
```

It took around 5-6 hours to compress (seems excessive). Compressed size is about 2.3 GB.

I then downloaded it to my main computer (Ubuntu, Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz). Every time I try to extract, it starts off at disappointing, but acceptable speed, but slows down to a crawl as it gets further along (ran overnight and when I woke up it was doing about 300 files per minute).

However, on my Windows machine (Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2687W @ 3.10GHz 3.10 GHz, which is only a slightly better machine, I extracted the entire directory in 15-20 minutes. It also clearly made use of multiple processors, which I can't get 7-Zip to do on Ubuntu.

Obviously I can't have an extraction take several days, nor should I.

My sense is this has to do with something I don't know about Ubuntu (I'm a recovering Windows user) or my file system rather than 7-Zip. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

My main computer uses ext4 file system, and the version of 7-Zip I have is 9.20:

7-Zip [64] 9.20 p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,12 CPUs)

**Update:**

> I should clarify that I actually have one drive on my main Ubuntu
>   installation that is ext4 (my ssd), though I have another one that is
>   ntfs (I think I remember this being recommended by Ubuntu during
>   installation, perhaps b/c I set it up as a raid array).  The problem
>   of slowing down over time was happening regardless of which I was
>   working from.
>
> Following advice in the comments, I used my Windows machine to unzip
>   the compressed file, restructure the directory with 4096
>   subdirectories, and re-zip it (though this time I used the default
>   compression level rather than maximum, and specified lzma2).  I then transferred it to my
>   Ubuntu machine (the ext4 SSD specifically) and unzipped.  It worked
>   perfectly as I would expect - very fast.
>
> However, as another commenter noted, part of the problem here is
>   likely just that my drives on the Ubuntu machine are not indexed (they
>   are on Windows), and I might not have to restructure directories at
>   all if I do index (which I've been wanting to do anyway).  I'm
>   currently trying to figure out how to do that successfully and
>   safely...and will report back with any useful results.
>
> I've also tried restructuring a directory already on my Ubuntu machine
>   using python, which is going unreasonably slow. Perhaps it's a python
>   issue rather than Linux/ext4/ntfs or perhaps it also has to do with 
>   indexing, or perhaps it is b/c the source directory has 2.2 million files 
>   in one directory...:

```
for fileName in series:
    if not os.path.exists('[...]/Pages2/' + fileName[:3] + '/' + fileName):
        shutil.copy('[...]/Pages/' + fileName, '[...]/Pages2/' + fileName[:3] + '/' + fileName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the actual answer when I read the wikipedia entry for XZ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz):

> One can think of xz as a stripped-down version of the 7-Zip program.
>   xz has its own file format rather than the .7z format used by ***7-Zip
>   (which lacks support for Unix-like file system metadata[2]).***

It is in fact okay to have millions of small files in a single directory, it would seem, on either NTFS or EXT-4 with Ubuntu (perhaps not advisable for other reasons however).  There was also nothing wrong with the indexing on my file systems.  The reason 7zip slows down when trying to extract a massive directory has everything to do with the writers of 7zip not caring much about Linux/Unix users.

This does half make me wonder whether whoever wrote Nautilus is similarly contemptuous of Linux users...b/c it really doesn't like directories with lots of files either, whereas Windows Explorer has no problems with it.

Comment: `Unix-like file system metadata` is the Unix permission `rwx` and has nothing to do with the speed. The 7z format is designed without Unix permission in mind, but that has no relation whatsoever with the p7zip program being slow

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about one directory with 2.2mil files? Ext Filesystems like to get slow when you work with that many files.

Comment: Correct, if they are not in various subdirectories, ext(2/3/4) filesystems will come to a crawl when you get to 100.000+ files in a directory. On XFS filesystems this will not happen that quickly, but it's never a good idea to have that many files in a single directory.

Comment: I see.  That's odd though b/c I do have several directories with over a million files in them on my Ubuntu machine and haven't had too much trouble with them when moving files around.  Also, the server I compressed the file with is using ext4, and the file compressed okay. I can try unzipping on my windows machine then rezipping after adding some structure to the directory.  Does Windows just have a far superior file system or something?

Comment: As @Sig-IO mentioned, this is an effect of many files in one directory, just because the file system isn't optimized for such a usage. If you distribute your files over several directories, it will act as fast as you used to know it.

Comment: Are you guys sure this is accurate?  Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTree " HTree indexes are used in the ext3 and ext4 Linux filesystems, and were incorporated into the Linux kernel around 2.5.40.[2] HTree indexing improved the scalability of Linux ext2 based filesystems from a practical limit of a few thousand files, into the range of tens of millions of files per directory."

Comment: @KCzar that's correct, but it needs to be explicitly enabled on the filesystem (it's the `dir_index` feature). If you have the rights to do so you can check whether it's enabled using `dumpe2fs`.

Comment: Can anyone either let me know what the proper method is to achieve on my Ubuntu machine even remotely comparable functionality and performance to my Windows file system or point me to an A-Z instruction page on how to do it? All I can find online are fragments of the explanations I'm looking for, and reformatting drives is something I have to get right. I would be very much obliged. Thanks.